# MimeKit .Net Core : The target process exited with code -1073741819 while evaluating the function "MimeKit.MimeMessage.ToString"

Tags: mailkit, mimekit

I am using Mimekit/Mailkit to forward mail in my .Net core app.
The system exits with the following error :
The target process exited with code -1073741819 while evaluating the function "MimeKit.MimeMessage.ToString"

While executing these lines:

```
   var builder = new BodyBuilder();
   builder.TextBody = forwardMail.Body ?? string.Empty;
   builder.Attachments.Add(new MessagePart { Message = message });
   message.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();
```

It is happening all the time. Why is this? How can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You are making the message recursive.

```
message.Body = something that embeds message
```

When you call ToString() on it, the message gets written first to a MemoryStream (and from there, gets converted into a string) and the MemoryStream buffer must continue growing without bounds because there is no end to a recursive message.

You likely meant to embed a *different* message, but your code has a body part of the message pointing back to the top-level message again resulting in an infinite loop when it gets written out.